# Add date to firebase

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Using Angularfire, I add date to my firebase database. I try this code.
In my html file i use date input

```
<input type="date" ng-model="user.todoDate">
```

and this is my angularfire function

```
  var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
  list.$add({ 
  date : $scope.user.inputDate
  })
```

kbut when using

`console.log($scope.user.inputDate)`
i get the hole date format (Mon Apr 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure dâÃ©tÃ©))).

How can i get only th jj/mm/aaaa format of date.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194977/how-to-input-a-time-into-firebase-with-angularfire) for how to store dates in Firebase.

Comment: it doesn't answer my question. I would store a date not a time even i change the type to date and use toString() function , i get the same result.

Comment: I need only the date as this form jj/mm/aaaa